# php array variable passed inside class and putted into array inside method

Tags: php, mysql, scope

Good evening everybody I'm struggling with this script. I have a MySql query which puts the result in an array. I need the result array to be accessible from inside a class and then I need to pass the data stored in another array that is already inside that class. EDIT --- I've finally made it and put all the query inside a `function target_query` of the class, and recall the function from the inside of `function ToFile` Now i need to put the `$arraytoclass` array inside `$readyForExport` array
Many thanks... I'm very close to finish!

```
   <?php
    class AdvancedClass extends MyModule {

        public function target_query(){
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "name";
        $password = "pass";
        $dbname = "db";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT codice_target FROM customer";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $arraytoclass = array();

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        //echo "tutto ok";
        while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        //echo "Codice target: " . $row["codice_target"]."<br>";
        $arraytoclass[] = $row;
        //echo "codice target:".$arraytoclass[$i]['codice_target']; 

        }
        //print_r($arraytoclass);

        } else {
        echo "0 results";
        }


        return $arraytoclass;
        print_r($arraytoclass);
        $conn->close();
        }

        public function ToFile($file, $allexportfields, $object, $ae) {

            $this->target_query();

            if ($allexportfields && $file && $object && $ae) {
                //one ready array for put 
                $readyForExport = array();

                $readyForExport['target'] = $arr_needed_in[1]['target'];

                echo '<pre> target' . var_dump($arr_needed_in[1]['target']) . '</pre>'; // STILL PRINT NULL
                //need to change user code with target
                //$readyForExport['target'] = 8989;
                // other methods 
                // other methods
                // other methods
            }
        }

    }
    ?>
```

EDIT: i have tried some ways and i discovered that if i use this code

```
$sql = "SELECT codice_target FROM customer";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$arraytoclass = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    //echo "tutto ok";
    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        //echo "Codice target: " . $row["codice_target"]."<br>";
        $arraytoclass[] = $row;
        //echo "codice target:".$arraytoclass[$i]['codice_target']; 

    }print_r($arraytoclass);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

the result is this one below, so meabe thats why with **fetch_assoc** returns null ... EDIT I put print_r($arraytoclass); outside the while and this is the result

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => 898989
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )
    )
```

etc.etc.

Comment: Why don't you do your queries inside of a function in your class? Also, you need to instantiate an instance of AdvancedClass (ex. $class_foo = new AdvancedClass();). For you to properly pass things into a class you need a constructor.

Comment: Do you instantiate the class? How do you know it is not working?

Comment: yes the class is instatiated, I summarized the code for maximum reading. it is not working because I've tried many ways and i putted `echo '<pre>' . var_dump($readyForExport) . '</pre>';` above the other var_dump command for debug. it prints NULL at screen...

Comment: I tried to do my queries inside the function but something gone wrong, I accept any suggest. thanks...

Comment: i would make the connection block into a class.

If not pass the `` $arraytoclass`` as a parameter to the ``AdvancedClass`` construct

Oh create a static method in ``AdvancedClass`` that is uses to set ``arraytoclass`` 

i mean ``global`` is not a good practice anyways

Comment: can you please edit the code for me ? You have to excuse me I dont understand your sentence precisely and I don't have the experience to do what you suggested... many thanks...

Comment: You can always use the constructor of the class and pass the data when the object is created like   $obj = new AdvancedClass ($arraytoclass). You can store them in a private variable then within the class

Comment: Can you please make an example of creating objects from that class ?

Comment: hi everyone, I've edited the code following your suggestions, please take a look and review

Comment: STILL GETTING NULL >_<

Comment: You have to populate $arraytoclass first before executing ToFile() or writeToFile() function, for the data to appear.

Comment: Since you're doing the `global` approach in - ToFile() - replace all `$arr_needed_in[1]['target']` with `$arraytoclass[1]['target']`

Comment: can you please help me Im stuck with this last step in populating the array and put it in the function ToFile()

Comment: The array $arraytoclass is populated since i've made debug with `print_r($arraytoclass);` outside the while loop at line 27 circa, i dont understand why is not replicating correctly down in the ToFile(); function...

Comment: I've edited the code and put the query code inside a public funtion, please review the code for passing the array from `function target_query` to `function ToFile`